# I installed matplotlib successfully but when I try to import it it gives an error with 'no module named matplotlib'

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, pycharm, installation

I installed python 3.7 on my pc (win 10). Later I tried to install matplotlib using a pip command, it installed and matplotlib is now also inside the pip list. When I go to the lib/site-packages folder where I saved python, it clearly has matplotlib inside of it. matplolib also works when us it in my command promt after using the 'python' command. But when I wanna import it in my project in pycharm, it does not work and no module is found.

I am new to all this and this is the first module I installed for python, so I can not figure out what I am doing wrong here. The version of matplotlib I am trying to install is 2.2.3.

Thx for any help

Comment: please show snips of your attempts...

Comment: which specific command did you use to install it? Did you use  `python3.7 -m pip install matplotlib`?

Comment: So the problem seems to be that you did not install matplotlib in the environment that PyCharm uses for which there are two solutions: 1) Install matplotlib in the environment you are running PyCharm with 2) change the environment that PyCharm uses.

Comment: Ok my problem is solved
@ImportanceOfBeingErnest was right. When I make a new protect in pycharm, i picked 'system interperter', instead of whatever it did last time, and now it all works. I dont rly understand why, but im guessing now its using all the side packages installed on the system?